# Summary statistic by levels of two separate categorical variables

Tags: r, group-by, dataframe, aggregate-functions

I have created the following dataframe

```
Group <- c('A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C')
YearWeek <-c('201401','201401','201401','201401','201401','201401','201401','201401','201401','201401')
Score1 <- c(404,440,395,500,450,476,350,500,600,575)
Group <- c('A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C')
YearWeek <-c('201401','201401','201401','201401','201401','201401','201401','201401','201401','201401','201402','201402','201402','201402','201402','201402','201402','201402','201402','201402')
Score1 <-c(404,440,395,500,450,476,350,500,600,575,460,445,400,508,470,422,368,555,700,634)
employee <- c(1:20)
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, Group, YearWeek, Score1)
```

I want to calculate the mean of group 'A' (my control group) by each level of 'YearWeek' and subtract it from Score1 for every employee (including the control group employees) according to the same YearWeek and add the result to the dataframe as a new variable 'Difference'

I tried first to obtain the mean for group 'A' (control group employees) but received the following error:

```
CTRLScore <- as.data.frame(employ.data[, j=list(mean(Score1),by = list(YearWeek,Group,"A"))]) 
Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

In addition: Warning message:

```
In `[.data.frame`(employ.data, , j = list(mean(Score1), by = list(YearWeek,  :
named arguments other than 'drop' are discouraged
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a strategy that I believe will work.

First calculate the mean for group A for each YearWeek

```
ctrlmeans <- with(subset(employ.data, Group=="A"), tapply(Score1, YearWeek, mean))
```

That returns a named vector. We can then use the YearWeek column of the data.frame as a look up into that table to subtract off the mean. We can do that with

```
Difference <- employ.data$Score1-ctrlmeans[employ.data$YearWeek]
```

and then add that back to the data.frame

```
employ.data$Difference <- Difference
```

Comment: Ok I've been trying to run this example on a much larger real data set and the resulting Difference vector is NA:

Comment: @user3594490 are there YearWeek's with no group A's? Can you identify what's different about your real data that's not represented in the sample? If it works on subsets of the list, try making the subset smaller till it breaks. Then figure out what's different about the last set of rows you added.

Comment: Must have something to do with duplicates in my data. I'll create some subsets are work through.

Comment: The method should not be affected by duplicates. Missing Score1 values, or YearWeek values with no Group A might be a problem.

Comment: All I can think of is that it has something to do with data type.  My file is a CSV file uploaded with read.csv command but I thought that was supposed to create a data frame.

Comment: I'm posting another question so that I can show the commands and output I'm receiving.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
library(reshape)
melted<-melt(employ.data)
casted<-cast(x,formula=Group+YearWeek~variable,subset=variable=="Score1",fun.aggregate=mean)

#Print Out 
casted

# Holder variables
addColumn <- NULL
i<-0

for(i in 1:nrow(employ.data))
{
  score <- employ.data[i,]$Score1
  group<-employ.data[i,]$Group
  yearWeek <- employ.data[i,]$YearWeek
  sub<-casted[casted$Group %in% group,]
  meanScore<-sub[sub$YearWeek %in% yearWeek,]$Score1
  addColumn <- c(addColumn,score-meanScore)
}

# Combine
cbind(employ.data,addColumn)
```

Comment: I don't happen to have any experience with reshape and will have to download the package to work through the solution you provided. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` variation on @MrFlick's answer:

```
# calculating the means
ctrlmeans <- with(subset(employ.data, Group=="A"), tapply(Score1, YearWeek, mean))

# adding the difference to the data.frame
require(dplyr)
employ.data <- employ.data %.%
  mutate(Difference = Score1 - ctrlmeans[employ.data$YearWeek])
```